# Compiling a Gluon project to an APK

Tags: apk, gluon

I just started using the (new) version of Gluon, had been using an older one by mistake and on the older version you just clicked "Run as.." then went to Gradle build options then you know the rest, but now that isn't an option so I'm not sure if theres an alternate method now or I just didn't install it correctly.

How do I compile a singleview project?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, follow this [tutorial](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/3.0.0/#eclipse-plugin), also try the samples [here](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/). Some of them, like Beacons, use Eclipse. See docs and source code.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'm using Gradle tasks and executing the "android" button but nothing is happening after I click it, it says launching gradle tasks then just stops with no output.

Comment: Make sure you have reviewed the list of prerequisites before, and then try to create a new project following the tutorial. Run it on desktop first, then deploy to your mobile. Use `gradlew --info androidInstall` on command line, so you can see the messages during the process. If this works, it should work as well from Eclipse